# What's a good way to filter a text file to remove empty lines?

Tags: shell, text-processing, sed, awk

I have a .csv file (on a mac) that has a bunch of empty lines, e.g.:

```
"1", "2", "lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum 

lorem ipsum ","2","3","4"
"1", "2", "lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum 

lorem ipsum ","2","3","4"
```

Which I want to convert to:

```
"1", "2", "lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum ","2","3","4"
"1", "2", "lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum ","2","3","4"
```

I know there must be a one liner but I don't know awk or sed. Any tips greatly appreciated!

Comment: According to that sample you actually want to remove embedded line breaks from the fields. Is that correct? In other words, there are 6 input lines and should be 2 output lines?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I am trying to get rid of: embedded newlines inside of a quoted string.

Comment: So what you need is something that removes newlines inside quotes. That's going to be a little more complicated, because you need multiline regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this would have been easier if I gave the file, but unfortunately it contained confidential info that I couldn't share. In the meanwhile I wrote me a ruby script that seemed to do the trick:

```
require 'csv'
c = CSV.open("outfile1.csv", "w")
CSV.foreach("data.csv", :encoding => 'windows-1251:utf-8') do |row|
  row = row.map { |a| a.class == String ? a.gsub(/\r/, '') : a}
  c << row
end
c.close
```

Thanks everyone for helping!

Answer (score 12):

You can use grep's `-v` (invert match) mode to do this:

```
grep -v '^$' old-file.csv > new-file.csv
```

Note that those need to be different files, because of how shell redirects work. The output file is opened (and emptied) before the input file is read. If you have moreutils (not by default on Mac OS X), you can use `sponge` to work around this:

```
grep -v '^$' file.csv | sponge file.csv
```

But of course, then you have a harder time going back if something goes wrong.

If you "blank lines" actually may contain spaces (it sounds like they do), then you can use this instead:

```
egrep -v '^[[:space:]]*$' old-file.csv > new-file.csv
```

That will ignore blank lines as well as lines containing only whitespace. You can of course do the same `sponge` transformation on it.

Comment: Thanks.... Didn't delete any empty lines...Maybe the ^$ is not matching? But the lines are empty to the  best of my knowledge. Remember this is a cdv created by excel on a mac... Does that say anything? (Don't run away screaming because I said Excel :)

Comment: @pitosalas They're probably not empty lines. Try changing it to `egrep -v '^[[:space:]]*$'` ... note grep -> egrep and the weird new pattern

Comment: Didnt work. Deleted a bunch of double quotes and made a mess...

Comment: @pitosalas I'm unsure how it'd delete double quotes. It should only be able to delete whitespace. And indeed, that's what it does when I test it on the example data you posted...

Comment: @pitosalas could you check if either of these commands spits out something that looks reasonable (as opposed to gibberish): `iconv -f utf16le file.csv | head` or `iconv -f utf16be file.csv | head`

Comment: In both cases: "iconv: conversion from utf16le unsupported"

Comment: @pitosalas ugh, how about just utf16 (without the be or le at the end)?

Answer (score 8):

The easiest option is just `grep .`. Here, the dot means "match anything", so if the line is empty, it is not matched. Otherwhise it prints the whole line as is.

Answer (score 6):

To remove empty lines, *in place*, with ksh93:

```
sed '/./!d' file 1<>; file
```

The `<>;` redirection operator is specific to ksh93 and is the same as the standard `<>` operator except that ksh truncates the file after the command has terminated.

`sed '/./!d'` is a convoluted way to write `grep .`, but unfortunately GNU grep at least complains if its stdout points to the same file as its stdin. You'd say one could write:

```
grep . file | cat 1<>; file
```

But unfortunately, there's a bug in ksh93 (at least my version (93u+)), in that the file seems to be truncated to zero length in that case.

```
grep . file | { cat; } 1<>; file
```

Seems to work around that bug, but now, it's far more convoluted than the sed command.

Comment: Please combine your answers into one well formatted entry with a quick guide for when each solution should be employed. The different approaches to different problems all jumbled together in floating answers has make this question a bit of a disaster to read.

Comment: @Caleb, It all boils down to the question being very unclear, so all of everybody's answers are for different interpretations of the question. For each answer, I tried to say which question it tries to answer.

Comment: Just FYI: Tried `awk '/./' file 1<>; file` which worked. To me, that's even clearer than `sed '/./!d'`

Answer (score 5):

Here's a `Perl` one-liner for it:

```
perl -pi -e 's/^\s*\n//' yourfile
```

EDIT: Improved code based on ruakh's comments below.

Comment: Or `perl -ni -e '/./ and print' yourfile`

Comment: Neat trick! I'll be adding that to my utility belt :)

Comment: Thanks.... Didn't delete any empty lines...Maybe the ^$ is not matching? But the lines are empty to the best of my knowledge. Remember this is a cdv created by excel on a mac... Does that say anything? (Don't run away screaming because I said Excel :)

Comment: Strange. I tested it on a Linux box and it works fine. 
The fact that it was produced by Excel should make no difference: it's still a plain text file.

Comment: MacOS and Windows use different EOL characters (and different from UNIX), which might be a problem.

Comment: @peterph AFAIK, `Perl`'s `\n` matches both types of EOL characters.

Comment: @JosephR it should. But looking at your regexp again, it seems there is a superfluous space between `$` and `\n`. And does the `$` exclude the newline itself?

Comment: @peterph `$` is an anchor (i.e. zero-width) so it excludes the newline. As to the superfluous space, it's the reason I added the `/x` I didn't want `Perl` to try interpolating `$\\` into the regex

Comment: You don't need the `$`, given that you have the `\n`. (Alternatively -- you don't need the `\n`, given that you have the `\s*` and the `$`; but I think `s/^\s*\n//` makes it clearer that the newline is removed.) You also don't need the `/m`; it has no effect on this command. And once you get rid of the `$` and the space, you won't need the `/x`.

Comment: @ruakh Agreed, the `/m` and `$` are unnecessary. I think that `\n`, however, can't be removed as using only `s/^\s*//` would remove leading whitespace from valid lines.

Comment: @JosephR.: The `\n` itself *can* be removed; what you can't do is remove *both* the `$` *and* the `\n`. So `s/^\s*//` would have the problem you describe, but `s/^\s*$//` would be fine, because of the `\s*` and the `$`. (Do you see what I mean?)

Comment: @ruakh I do but `s/^\s*$//` wouldn't eat the newline, which is what we want in the first place. All that would result is that lines consisting of whitespace only will become truly empty lines. `\s*` will have no chance of matching a newline because `$` is an anchor that by definition occurs _before_ a newline.

Comment: @ruakh Scratch that. I tried `s/^\s*$//` and it worked. It seems I'm missing something. Would you be so kind as to enlighten me?

Comment: @JosephR.: What happens is, `$` *can* match before a newline (provided that either the `/m` flag is enabled, or the newline is the very last character of the string, or both), but it can *also* match the end of the string. For example, `"abc" =~ m/^abc$/` is true. In the case of `\s*$`, the `\s*` is greedy enough to eat up the newline, and then the `$` matches the end-of-string. (But I think `s/^\s*\n//` is clearer, anyway, so your answer is just fine as it is now.)

Answer (score 5):

Based on the clarification in the comments to your question, something like:

```
awk -v RS= -v ORS= 1
```

may do what you want.

An empty *record separator* is a special case that tells `awk` that records are to be paragraphs (separated by sequences of empty lines). Setting the *output record separator* to the empty string as well means that the content of those paragraphs (without the separators) are to be concatenated. `1` is just a *true* condition to print every record.

That would however omit the trailing newline, so you could do:

```
awk -v RS= -v ORS= '1;END{if (NR) printf "\n"}'
```

Answer (score 2):

I found an idea for a possible solution on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1252191/1095932).

`sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/[^"]\n\s*\n/ /g' file.csv`

You should probably backup your csv file before testing it, but at least for the example you provided it works flawlessly.

A good explanation about the inner workings of this expression is offered at the answer, I just edited it to look for lines that do not end with a `"` (`[^"]\n`).

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '
    length == 0 {next} 
    /^[^"]/ && /"$/ {print; next} 
    {printf("%s", $0)}
' filename
```

produces

```
"1", "2", "lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum ","2","3","4"
"1", "2", "lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum ","2","3","4"
```

Answer (score 1):

If, from your own response, you want to remove newline characters contained inside quoted strings, you could do:

```
 perl -0777 -pe 's/".*?"/$_=$&;s:\n::g;$_/gse'
```

You could also use use perl's `-i` flag to edit the files *in place*.

```
 perl -0777 -pe 's/".*?"/$_=$&;s:\n::g;$_/gse' file1 file2...
```

Or with GNU awk:

```
 awk -v RS=\" 'NR%2==0 {gsub("\n","")}; {printf "%s", $0 RT}'
```

or:

```
 awk -vRS=\" '1-NR%2{gsub("\n","")}{ORS=RT}1'
```

(if you're competing for the shortest one)

Note that those assume that there are no *escaped* double quote characters in the input.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in effect that you want more than removing empty lines, but remove every  sequence of 2 or more newline characters.

Which you could do with perl:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\n{2,}//gs' file
```

You could also use use perl's `-i` flag to edit the files *in place*.

```
perl -0777 -pi -e 's/\n{2,}//gs' file1 file2...
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an ever shorter way of removing empty lines in `AWK`:

`awk 'NF' file`

But to get the output you want, all is needed is a simple one liner:

`awk 'NF {printf("%s ", $0); i++;} !(i % 2) {printf("\n");}' file`

**Explanation**

In `AWK`, an empty line means the row/record has no fields, that is, the `NF` (Number of Fields) variable is zero. The one liner above will only execute when `NF > 0`, printing all lines, but the empty ones.

The `i++` is the non-empty lines counter.

The `!(i % 2)` is used in order to print two consecutive non-empty lines in the way of your desired output, that is, every time a multiple of 2 is found, the `modulo` statement `!(i % 2)` yields 1, what terminates the concatenation of two non-empty lines.

Comment: My bad! Sorry. I didn't read his whole question and the desired output. The reply is fixed now. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc v/./d -cx b.csv
```

1. `v/./` find empty lines
2. `d` delete
3. `x` save and close