# Problem Counting the lines of a text file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to be able to get the number of non-empty lines in a text file.

Suppose I have num.txt with the contents:

```
10

10
12
15
24
31
32
```

Here there are 8 lines, with only 7 that are not empty. How do I find how many lines are not empty?

Edit:
Problem solved using the following command

To count non-empty lines (or rather, lines with anything other than whitespace on them):

$ grep -c -v '^[[:space:]]*$' num.txt

Comment: Please paste actual text, **not** screenshots.

Comment: Also it looks like you just have empty lines (and possibly non-printing characters) in your file.  `cat` confirms this.  But the standard tool to count lines of a file is `wc`, e.g. with `wc -l num.txt`.

Comment: I do not get it, i mean i am posting screenshots just to make sure you know what am i using and formatting the topic is not working on my browser so i had to

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/57016/135943

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `wc` (word-count) utility is able to count lines in a file:

```
$ wc -l num.txt
```

... or rather, it counts the number of newlines in the file, which most of the time is the same thing (actually, on a Unix system, that is *defined* as the same thing). The manual (on Mac OS X) states: "Characters beyond the final
     `<newline>` character will not be included in the line count."

The reason you are mildly confused is probably because you don't think of empty lines as lines at all, but they are.

To count *non-empty* lines (or rather, lines with anything other than whitespace on them):

```
$ grep -c -v '^[[:space:]]*$' num.txt
```

Comment: How can i do that :P

Comment: Like you just seem to have done :-)  That shows that the question has actually been formally resolved. .